# Lost lines when transfer text from a table to a shape in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, text, powerpoint, shapes

I have been working on a PowerPoint presentation for a game show at my high school. I tried to import questions from a PowerPoint table like this:

[image]

using the code as follows:

```
Slide1.Shapes("question").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.Slides(6).Shapes(1).Table.Cell(k + x, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
Slide1.Shapes("answer").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.Slides(6).Shapes(1).Table.Cell(k + x, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
```

with k and x being variables for my question number calculating method (which is not related to the problem).

The problem that I encounter is some of the text transferred are missing while the code is running, for example:

[image]

This occasionally happens from time to time, with the text only appearing a few beginning lines and the rest are not shown.

When I escaped the slide show and then show it again (without the code running and the data is still there), the text appears just fine:

[image]

Even when the code is running and the error occurs on the slide show, when I Alt+Tab to see the editor window the text is still there fully.

I couldn't figure out anything for days now. Please help me, I'd be very grateful if you did so.

Comment: Okay, I tried removing the animations on the shapes containing the question and the answer and it worked like a charm. Is it possible that animation has something to do with this? If that's so, why the hell doesn't Microsoft update VBA for Office after years?

Comment: If I understand your question, it sounds like your code is working correctly, but PowerPoint is not updating the screen correctly while the code is running. To overcome this problem in Word and Excel, you would use Application.ScreenUpdating = False while the code is running to prevent this. In PowerPoint, you can use the code on this page to create the equivalent command: http://skp.mvps.org/ppt00033.htm

Comment: I'm using Office 365 which is unsupported by the code. Do you have anything that supports mine?

Comment: Office 365 uses exactly the same VBA as Office 2019, unless you're using a Mac. If you see an error message, please post the message.

Comment: The message shows that the version is unsupported. It's a message created within the code you sent me, I can tell from the custom notification text. And according to the code it only supports up to Office 2013.

Comment: In the Select Case section add

     Case "16" ' For 2016 and 2019:
      hwnd = FindWindow("PPTFrameClass", 0&)

to handle PowerPoint 2016 and 2019. If you still have issues, you may be running a 64-bit version of Office which requires the addition of PtrSafe to Declarations and also needs Long to be changed to LongPtr. Here is Microsoft's page about revisions for 64-bit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview